Light goes through character
I dont know what exactly happen much. But I use shader node and use emission as light source on object. the problem I talking about is the light line that got through into character so anyway to fix shader?


Thanks so much for answer also.

Hello are you using the Compositor?

It looks like a composited effect, so it may be necessary to render the character (and everything in front of her) to a different layer and lay it on top.

I didnt use compositer. And I just know there is a compositer to adjust it. well thanks for answer so much!

In your render, we can see straight lens flares:

These are achieved from the compositor using a Glare node in Streaks mode:

If you don't want them at all, you can select the node and hit ⎈ CtrlX to "dissolve it" (aka remove it but preserving the connections).
If you want to keep this effect, but have it less pronounced, you could lower its Mix property in the negatives:

If you want to keep the effect but not have it shown in front of the characters, then as @Allen Simpson mentionned, you should layer things in compositor. One way to do that is by making multiple view layers, with each of them different visible collections, so that you can render things individually and layer them in comp. But a simpler solution is to use a Cryptomatte.
In your Viewlayer's pass properties, enable Object Cryptomatte:

Since it's a pass, we need to render it, but we don't need a full quality render, so to not waste time you can lower your render samples for a quick and dirty preview.
In the compositor, add a Cryptomatte node, to which you plug your Render Layer node's Image output:

It should automatically select the scene and layer type.
Plug your Preview node to the Pick output (⎈ Ctrl⇧ Shift LMB with node wrangler), it will let you see each object as a unique flat color and you can "select" them using the + button near the Matte ID text box, and then click the colors you want to add.

This creates an image of your selection on a transparent background, and a BW mask.
You can mix it with your glare node output using a Color Mix node, and enable the Alpha option next to the Mix dorpdown:

